# Number of distinct solutions of $P_n(z) = w$ for different values of $w$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Suppose $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with complex coefficients and $n > 1$. Then the equation $P_n(z) = w$ has $n$ solutions (counting multiplicities) for every complex number $w$. It can be shown using the derivative of $P_n$, that the number of complex numbers, for which the equation above has less than $n$ **distinct** solutions is at most $n - 1$. Even though differentiation is elementary enough, I think there should be a proof of this which uses only the most simple algebraic ideas and, of course, the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra but I couldn't come up with such a proof. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You don't need to know any calculus to talk about the derivative of a polynomial, you can just define it formally and prove that it has the required properties.

Comment: I am aware of this but introducing derivatives into the proof, be it analytical or algebraic, feels like using a powerful technique for a simple looking problem. I was wondering whether that step was really necessary. On second thought, the derivative seems to be the most natural tool to use in this context.

Comment: The other way I know to answer this question is by proving one way or another that the discriminant exists and has certain properties (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant). Would you consider that more or less elementary? I don't consider this problem simple at all, incidentally.